# Error al subir mi pagina web con GitHubPage (build with jekyll)

Tags: github-pages

Alguien me puede orientar con este problema, hace 2 semanas creo, quise subir una página web con GitHub Page, pero me dio un problema del cual no se resolver me dio el siguiente mensaje:

```
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss': No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs
```

La página solo es un clon de Google no tiene nada de especial. Ya había subido varias veces otras páginas web pero ninguna me había dado problemas hasta ahora.
[image: Iamgen 1]

[image: mensaje de error al subir con github pages]

Comment: estas seguro que subiste el archivo `assets/css/style.scss`?

Comment: @RuslanLópez de hecho si y no, me explico, para ese proyecto en ningún momento use un archivo con extensión **.scss** el que si cree es un **.css**. [Acá](https://github.com/Noriega402/cloneGoogle) dejo el repositorio para que se pueda entender mejor.